# Add 8AM UTC to a date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date something like below :

```
Thu Nov 29 18:00:00 CST 2018
Thu Apr 26 01:00:00 BST 2018
```

I need to convert it to 8AM UTC in oracle.
How do i do this ?
It is a string not date.

Referred link deals with proper dates and there is no accepted answer for it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: 8am UTC on which date? The local date, or the date after that has been converted to UTC? Also note that abbreviations such as "BST" or "CST" are often ambiguous, and should be avoided as far as possible - you'll at least need to account for that in your approach, too.

Comment: I doubt you have `Thu Nov 29 18:00:00 CST 2018` in Oracle. What do you mean by "convert it to 8AM UTC"?

Comment: Expected results : Thu Nov 29 08:00:00 GMT 2018

Comment: @DaisyShipton These dates have been generated through a Angular plugin.

Comment: Maybe the Angular plugin can give you the value in a different form, such as ISO-8601, which would be easier to parse and convert? Or perhaps it can convert to UTC itself. If you're stuck with CST/BST then you'll need to define how those translate to something Oracle can recognise; so hopefully they are not ambiguous in your data (i.e. it's all from a small number of time zones). Or are you ignoring the original time completely and just keeping the date - even if the UTC-adjusted time would be a different day? It isn't obvious how you get from 18:00 to 08:00.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse any string to Sql date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181484/parse-any-string-to-sql-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a string you could use `regexp_replace`.

```
regexp_replace(nmuloc, '[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2} [A-Z]{3}', '08:00:00 GMT')
```

Comment: select regexp_replace(val, '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3}', '08:00:00 GMT') from table;  even this ill work.

Comment: Hi, i got the output as expected . Thu Nov 29 08:00:00 GMT 2018. Now i need to convert this to epoch date . Is there any way ?

Comment: To convert to epoch date the format has to be in Thu Nov 29 2018 08:00:00 GMT.So how do we go about this ?

Comment: Do you really think hard coded `08:00:00 GMT` is sufficient?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Well, it's what the OP called for. Possible, that they want something else but how to know if they didn't ask for it?

Comment: @DivyaRao: You should consider transforming the type from `varchar2` to `date`. It'd allow to use `to_char()` to get a representation in almost any format. Plus it ensures the data is sane.

Comment: Yes of course, strictly speaking your solution provides the desired result. However, I don't think that is what is OP is looking for - even thought the question is rather unclear and less specific.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( datetime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE );

INSERT INTO table_name
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-11-29 18:00:00 CST' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-04-26 01:00:00 Europe/London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-06-26 00:00:00 Europe/London' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

- Use `datetime AS TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to convert it from your time zone to UTC
- Then use `TRUNC()` to truncate it back to the start of the UTC day (and also cast it to a date)
- Because its now a date, use `CAST( ... AS TIMESTAMP )` to get it back to a timestamp
- Then use `FROM_TZ( ..., 'UTC' )` to get it to be a timestamp in the UTC time zone
- Then add `INTERVAL '8' HOUR` to be 8am.

Like this:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(
         CAST(
           TRUNC( datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' )
           AS TIMESTAMP
         ),
         'UTC'
       ) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR AS utc_date_at_8am_utc
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
UTC_DATE_AT_8AM_UTC
--------------------------------
30-NOV-18 08.00.00.000000 AM UTC
26-APR-18 08.00.00.000000 AM UTC
25-JUN-18 08.00.00.000000 AM UTC
```

Note: this translates `2018-06-26 00:00:00 BST` to `2018-06-25 23:00:00 UTC` before truncating. So it will be the same UTC day (but not necessarily the same day in the local time zone).

**Query 2**

If this is an issue then just remove the initial time zone conversion:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(
         CAST(
           TRUNC( datetime )
           AS TIMESTAMP
         ),
         'UTC'
       ) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR AS date_at_8am_utc
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

```
DATE_AT_8AM_UTC
--------------------------------
29-NOV-18 08.00.00.000000 AM UTC
26-APR-18 08.00.00.000000 AM UTC
26-JUN-18 08.00.00.000000 AM UTC
```